# JavaScript - target a string between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to manipulate some HTML that I have no direct control over.

There are two elements that I could target with JavaScript, and then some ... well, sort of floating text between them.

```
    <div id="anOuterDiv">

  <div class="variousOtherElements">blah can contain dashes - oh yes it can</div>

  <div class="someOtherElements">blah can contain dashes - oh yes it can</div>

  <span class="branch">Some City Public Library</span> - <span class="location">Story Room</span>

</div>
```

Basically, I just need to remove or hide span.branch and span.location ... AND the dash between them. Right now I'm hiding the two spans via CSS, and the dash is just floating out there ...

The content of all elements can vary. There can be dashes in the other elements.

Either a jQuery or pure JavaScript solution would be useful. I have not been able to figure out a way to target this dash that is just hanging out there. I need to hide it and have it not take up space.

Comment: Curious, why can't you wrap the hypen in an element, or wrap the whole  branch/location line in an element?

Comment: I don't have any control over this HTML; it is built by external JavaScript from an external service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the elements with *branch* and *location* classes in a new div (container of their own), along with any siblings in between.  You can then hide or remove them as desired:

#### [see Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/s9BjQGrfOQevcBHA0Cmy)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.branch').each(function() {

    var to_wrap   = [this];
    var _sib      = this;
    var _continue = true;

    while (_continue && (_sib = _sib.nextSibling) && (_sib.className === undefined || _sib.className == 'location')) {
      to_wrap[to_wrap.length] = _sib;

      if (_sib.className == 'location')
        _continue = false;
    }

    buildHiddenDivRow(to_wrap, $(this).parent());

  });

});


function buildHiddenDivRow(arr, $parentElement) {
  $('<div />', {
    'class': 'branch-location',
    'style': 'display:none'
  }).prepend(arr).appendTo($parentElement);
}
```

I didn't give the algorithm much thought, but I did clean it up some.  I'm sure there is plenty of room for optimization and making it more concise and/or readable.

#### Caveats:

1. this does not preserve ordering, it only puts it at the end of the container, *anOuterDiv*
2. it doesn't look for textnodes or any elements specifically, it looks for an exact match by className.  If the element with *location* class has an additional class (e.g., `class="location span"`), or there is no element that has a *location* class, this will result in an infinite-loop and hang the browser.

For these reasons and more, ***use this as a reference and not production-ready code***.

Comment: Just thinking back on this, I may have been wrong about an infinite loop.  If no elements have the class, I think it might traverse the dom until there are no more child nodes found, so nextSibling could result in `undefined`, which would terminate the loop.  Then again, some browsers may set the nextSibling of last element to itself, so the loop would continually cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply CSS on a TextNode.

You may want to wrap it into a `<span>` then hide it. Or just set it to blank.

You may use `document.querySelector('.branch').nextSibling` to locate it.

For example:

```
document.querySelector('.branch').nextSibling.textContent = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a hidden span around the text node (the dash) like this:

```
var dashTextNode = $('.branch')[0].nextSibling;  //this will get the dash after .branch span
$(dashTextNode).wrap('<span style="display:none"></style>');
```

Comment: Hmm, this works to hide the first one, but for some reason if I try a loop it doesn't work on any of them.